# dynamically show site owners web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

We have over 200 sites. We want to have a centralized list that has all the site owners. We want to have a web part to display the owner of the site.

If we edit the list then the web part changes automatically. is this possible with SharePoint? What web part should we be using to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have to develop a custom web part using SPFx for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no such web parts in SharePoint online to display the owners of the sites. You can use SPFx to customize such a web part.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no SharePoint online out of the box web part available for your requirements to show the site owners on page.

You will have to develop a custom web part using SPFx on your own for your requirements.

Check below documentation to get started with SPFx and SPFx web parts:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Check this GitHub repository where all custom web part samples submitted by community contributor are available: [SharePoint FrameWork client-side web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples) - this will help you to get started with

---

You can easily get the associated owners group of a SharePoint site using PnP JS

```
// Gets the associated owners group of a web
const ownerGroup = await sp.web.associatedOwnerGroup();
```

**Reference**: [SP PnP JS - site groups](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/site-groups/)

Once you get the group details and group ID, you can use SharePoint REST API to get the members of group.